# concatenate 2 columns into one and display as list in a different cell

Tags: excel, list, concatenation

I have two columns A and B with for example:

```
A     B
aa    1
bb    2
cc    3
dd    4
```

I want another cell in the sheet to be a list of the concatenate of them 
so C3 will be: aa 1, bb 2, cc 3, dd 4

That is for instance for a single row `CONCATENATE(A1 & " " & B1)`.

How do I do it for this and display as a list?

Comment: I don't think this can be done with just a formula, you'll need VBA.

Comment: `display as a list` Can you please clarify or illustrate how you want it displayed

Comment: I mean a cell with a data validation of a list and an in cell dropdown list button. and the source of the list will be a concatenate of a possible growing\dynamicaly table with two columns A and B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To use the concatenated output as list input for a data validation:**

Presuming you have concatenated list in column c starting from C2;

**Step 1**: Create a named range and enter this formula in the `Refers to:` field;
`=Sheet1!$C$2:INDEX(Sheet1!$C$2:$C$1000,COUNTA(Sheet1!$C$2:$C$1000))`

[image]
**Step 2**: Use the name created as input in the data validation:
[image]

Comment: Hi! Where is A and B in this?

Answer (score 0):

try `=concatenate(A1," ",B1,",",A2," ",B1,",")`

Comment: This could work if the lists are small and fixed in size, but otherwise it's not very efficient to write this.

Comment: not efficient since they are not short and I'm searching for a way to do it dynamically.